# Server side login for Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to communicate with the Active Directory B2C from my backend to manage users. This seems possible here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

However, I don't see how to get a login token (or cookies) for a user so the server can send it back to the front-end to have it logged-in. How is it possible to implement this scenario?

I have seen this link but it refer to OAuth.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure B2C auth flow cannot generate an access token for Microsoft Graph.

You need to implement AAD auth flow by following [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) or [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user).

Comment: Thanks Allen. However, I'm looking for backend API with admin rights to get login token for a user without any consents involved. Something like - lookup user, run some validations and if ok, get the a token for login to be sent back to the front-end (to have the user logged-in).

Comment: @Gilad The AAD token does not work like this. It should be like this: you enter your credentials to log in, redirect to AAD idp for authentication, and then MS returns you a token. So in this case, my suggestion is use Azure B2C authentication for your login to the server, and use client credentials flow ([Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)) to get the access token for Microsoft Graph. You can call Microsoft Graph in the server side directly and then return the data to front end.

Comment: Thanks Allen. In the example they have GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/12345678-73a6-4952-a53a-e9916737ff7f to get some user data. is there a similar call to get the a token for that user that can be sent back to the front-end and have the user logged-in?

Comment: @Gilad No. You can only get the access token like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token. And the token can directly be used to call Microsoft Graph API. It doesn't have a feature having the user logged-in.